# ¿Como abrir paginas dentro de un iframe condicionada por un option?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, select, iframe

Buen día. Tengo un campo tipo select y quiero hacer que en base al reultado que se seleccione en el, me abra una pagina dentro de un iframe obviamente condicionada por el select ya que puede abrir 4 opciones diferentes.

1
        2
        3
        4

//aqui es donde debe abrirse la pagina que se seleccione en el select.

Espero que alguin pueda ayudarme..

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido Juan, te sugiero revisar [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas ya que fue marcada como baja calidad. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Si usas Bootstrap, usas jQuery. Si usas jQuery, puedes simplemente definir un `<div>` en donde mostrar el contenido que deseas si necesidad de usar un `iframe`.

Para lograrlo solo debes definir tu div:

```
<div id="show"></div>
```

y con jQuery usar la función [`load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

```js
<script>
    $("#option").on("change", function(){
        //A continuación tomamos el valor del select (option) y elegimos qué mostrar
        switch($(this).val()){
            case "1":
                $("#show").load("/pagina1.php");
            break;
            case "2":
                $("#show").load("/pagina2.php");
            break;
            case "3":
                $("#show").load("/pagina3.php");
            break;
            case "4":
                $("#show").load("/pagina4.php");
            break;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Incluso puedes ser más específico y definir qué sección de la página quieres cargar:

```
$("#show").load("/pagina2.php body");
```

y definir alguna acción para cuando la carga del documento termine:

```
$("#show").load("/pagina2.php form", function(){
    $("#inputDePagina2").focus();
});
```